# Binary RPC in node.js

Tags: json, rpc, avro

In general, supposing your server, written in Javascript in the node.js environment, is assembling a response to an end user from services provided by other servers, is there any reasonable alternative to having them all talk JSON?

RPC calls usually use XDR, which is binary, or JSON, which is ascii.  There are handy libraries to take care of all the boring sockets stuff for you for these cases.

Node.js tools to use RPC are available for RPC in JSON, but is there any easy way to access RPC calls in binary formats such as XDR, ASN.1 PER, or Avro Apache from node.js. Or to do something similar?

I am not asking what is the best way, or what can be done, because anything can be done with enough hard work, but rather what ways have standards to avoid reinventing the wheel, and libraries to do as much of the work as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[`avsc`](https://github.com/mtth/avsc) implements Avro's RPC specification, you can use it to expose "type-safe" services over any transport (e.g. HTTP, TCP, WebSockets). The [quickstart guide](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki/Quickstart#services) goes through a simple example that should help you get started. (Disclaimer: I wrote it.)

Comment: Your avro is in javascript, and is, I assume, expected to run under node.js

Apache provides avro to run as compiled C++, Java, Python, and C#.  So it looks like an Avro service communicating in binary can communicate between any two environments - also avro can serialize to memory, which should make possible operating system and compiler independent hashing of data.

Looks like a standardized solution.

So this would seem to imply that Avro services adequately cover anyone who wants to talk to anyone in any environment.